# Conditional variables on base of template value

Tags: c++, templates

I want to build a generic (math) `Vector` struct, with template defined size.

Now I want to make it possible to access the values via `x`, `y` and `z`, but only if the `Vector` size is big enough.

Example Code:

```
template <unsigned int s, typename T>
struct Vector {

  // Vector Data array
  T v[s];

  // Special vars
  T& x = v[0];
  T& y = v[1];
  T& z = v[2];

  Vector(): v{0} {}

  // some vector functions
};
```

Now consider the following:

```
Vector<2, float> vf2;

// should be possible
vf2.x;
// should be impossible
vf2.z;

Vector<3, float> vf3;

// should both be possible
vf3.x;
vf3.z;
```

The `vf2.z` part should throw an error at compile time and, because of the functions, I do not want to duplicate the `Vector` struct.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use template specialisation to achieve that behaviour.

Comment: I don't agree with the person that wrote the answer below when he says that you always need to call a method that throws an exception.  @Mansoor had a good suggestion: https://onlinegdb.com/rye3-ucJv

Comment: You are setting all the values to zero, which is not what he is asking....

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes that is a good suggestion from Mansoor, but if the struct has for example 20 functions, I do not want to copy them to multiple classes, otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Adding member references just to make member access cleaner is a horrible idea. (It adds memory overhead, and you'll need custom `operator=` to make it assignable...) Either replace the references with setters and getters, or even better: remove the array, remplate the references with `T x, y, z;` (you'll have to figure out how to conditionally include `z`, the best way is probably to specialize the template), and overload `operator[]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thats what I suggested but these folks want to go down that rabbit hole...

Comment: @YunfeiChen You never suggested specialising the template, which is probably the only way to conditionally include `z` so I'm not sure what you had in mind.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I find a much easier way to solve your problem so here goes...

First of all I need to see something about your class design, it is not a good design, if you want everything to be public use a struct not a class, secondly, if you want to check something you need to write a method for it, so something like:

```
template <unsigned int s, typename T>
class Vector {
public:
  T v[s];
  T& x = v[0];
  T& y = v[1];
  T& z = v[2];
  int getSize(){
    return s;
   };
};
```

Then in your driver you do something like:

```
Vector<2, float> vf2;
if(vf2.getSize() > 2){
   vf2.x;
   vf2.z;
}
else{
   vf2.z
   cout << "x cannot be called because size is too small.";
}
```

//do the same for the rest....

Comment: Yes, I could have used a struct, it is a good point, but I explicitly wanted a compile time check if you can access for example `myVector.z`. So I do not see where your solution solves the problem I stated.

Comment: Not to mention you do not even have a constructor, how do you even create an object, or the fact that you never intialized your array values....